undefined is not a function. Graphql + apollo + react native
In my react native project I'm using graphql codegen to generate types and hooks. I'm using react native 0.74.5. But I don't know why I have an error, so that is why I can't launch my app.
also here is my codegen.ts.
import type { CodegenConfig } from '@graphql-codegen/cli';

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  overwrite: true,
  schema: 'http://localhost:1337/graphql',
  documents: ['src/graphql/**/*.graphql'],
  hooks: {
    afterAllFileWrite: ['npx lint ts --fix'],
  },
  ignoreNoDocuments: true,
  emitLegacyCommonJSImports: true,
  config: {
    namingConvention: {
      transformUnderscore: true,
    },
    maybeValue: 'T | null | undefined',
    inputMaybeValue: 'T | null | undefined',
    experimentalFragmentVariables: true,
    scalars: {
      Date: 'string',
      DateTime: 'Date',
      I18NLocaleCode: 'string',
      JSON: 'Record<string, any|any[]|string|number|boolean|null|undefined>|any[]',
      Long: 'number',
      Time: 'string',
      Upload: 'unknown',
    },
  },
  generates: {
    'src/graphql/index.ts': {
      plugins: [
        {
          'fragment-matcher': {
            useExplicitTyping: true,
            module: 'es2015',
          },
        },
        {
          'typescript-react-apollo': {
            dedupeFragments: true,
            optimizeDocumentNode: true,
            addDocBlocks: false,
            withComponent: false,
            withHooks: true,
            withMutationOptionsType: false,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    'src/types/graphql.d.ts': {
      config: {
        noExport: true,
        skipTypename: true,
        enumsAsTypes: true,
      },
      plugins: ['typescript', 'typescript-operations'],
    },
    './graphql.schema.json': {
      plugins: ['introspection'],
    },
  },
};

export default config;


here is my error
I've tried to delete all generated files and generate it again. Also I've tried to remove node_modules, yarn.lock, pod files and after that reinstall all of these. Also I've added cjs files support to my metro.config.js(here is below).
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require('@react-native/metro-config');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
const { assetExts, sourceExts } = defaultConfig.resolver;

/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const config = {
  transformer: {
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
    sourceExts: process.env.RN_SRC_EXT
      ? [...process.env.RN_SRC_EXT.split(',').concat(sourceExts), 'cjs']
      : [...sourceExts, 'svg', 'jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs'],
  },
};

module.exports = mergeConfig(defaultConfig, config);


It seems that you don't have graphql-tag installed - make sure to install that package.

I've installed and it doesn't work

@rakhlinskyi Is it imported in the file where gql is used?

If not, you probably have to add a plugin for that.
